# Dynamically set angular environment inside the docker with daemon off

Tags: angular, linux, docker, nginx

```
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.sample.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

I am trying to dynamically map the API_URL to environment.ts by passing the argument (--env API_URL="http://..."),

Is it ok to provide `exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'` in the production environment? or any other possibilities?